# Android NDK shared variable between java and C

Tags: android, android-ndk

In NDK i know how to pass parameters from Java to C and then return values from C to Java.

But can we have some array which i can access from both Java and C simultaneously. Means i can add values in that array from C and after adding one value or 3-4 values i can access those values from Java?

If this is not feasible can we have something else using which i can get those values simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put array, etc. in the Java code and use JNI to access it from native code (JNI goes both ways). Needless to say, you need to be careful. BTW, you can't really 'add values' to an array in Java. If you really mean 'add' and not 'store', you might need a list or another dynamic structure.

Comment: So u mean to say that i can pass an empty array from Java to C and then store some values in that array from C and then say after storing 4-5 values from C , i try to access same array from Java then it will have those values?

Comment: Yes. Read the reference for more details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html#wp16536

Comment: One caveat: if you want to cache the array reference and use it in subsequent JNI calls, you need to convert it to a global ref.